# find word/string in string , do I need regex?

Tags: php, regex, string, parsing, extract

I have the following String:

```
... 12:32 +0304] "GET /test.php?param=value ....
```

I want to extract the *test.php* out of this String. I tried to find a php function which could do this but there was nothing helpful. So my next guess was, what about regex and I tried for so long to get the part between GET / and ?. I failed badly...

Does a function in php exists which could help me out or do I need regex for this? If I do so, how can I get a string out of a string? Important, I don't want to know if test.php is in the string. I want to get everything between GET / and ?.

Comment: PHP string functions can easily do this without needing any regex.

Comment: do you know the name ?

Comment: By the way this looks like an apache log, and if it is and you can control the server configuration, you can change to something you can parse more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex extracting anything between `GET /` and `?` in a capture group:

```
GET \/(.*?)\?
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/wR9yM5/1

In PHP it can be used like this:

```
$str = '... 12:32 +0304] "GET /test.php?param=value ....';
preg_match('/GET \/(.*?)\?/', $str, $re);
print_r($re[1]);
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/0XzZwo

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    $string     =   '... 12:32 +0304] "GET /test.php?param=value ....';
    $find       =   explode("GET /", explode(".php", $string)[0])[1].".php";
    echo $find; // test.php
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?>(\/))(\w+.php)
```

Or if You want any extention, 2 or 3 digits:

```
(?>(\/))(\w+.\w{3})
```

If only 3, delete "2," from brackets.

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
$subject='12:32 +0304] "GET /test.php?param=value';
$pattern='/(?>(\/))(\w+.{2,3})/s';
if (preg_match($pattern, $subject, $match))
echo $match[0];
?>
```

Comment: this is a match, but I cant extract the part :/ And maybe you could explain this line, I really can't handle regex yet

Comment: Edit's have been made.

Answer (score 0):

Without regex:

```
function between_solidus_and_question_mark($str) {
    $start  = strtok($str, '/');
    $middle = strtok('?');
    $end    = strtok(null); 

    if($start && $end) {
        return $middle;
    }
}

$str       = '... 12:32 +0304] "GET /test.php?param=value ....';
var_dump(between_solidus_and_question_mark($str));
```

Outputs:

```
test.php
```